# Argument data type numeric is invalid for argument 3 of convert function

Tags: replace, rounding, type-conversion, case-when

I have a varchar field that contains numbers i need to convert to decimal and remove commas before doing calculations. I am getting a numeric is invalid for argument 3 of convert.

Using these values as an example.

```
Value varchar(8000) = 12,545
Pct_cmpt decimal(8,2) = 23.00 

SELECT
CONVERT(decimal(18,2),replace(value,',',''),ROUND(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(VALUE) = 1 THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(numeric, VALUE),0) *Pct_Cmpt/100  ELSE 0   END,2)) as Earned
```

Argument data type numeric is invalid for argument 3 of convert function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out after scratching my head for awhile. I had to move my REPLACE function inside the CASE WHEN to get the CONVERT to work.

```
Select
CONVERT(decimal(18,2),ROUND(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(VALUE) = 1 THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(numeric,replace(value, ',','')),0)*PCT_CMPT/100 ELSE 0   END,2)) as Earned
```